# Activate keyboard on activity in background

Tags: android

I implemented an invisible click through activity in my application with setting the theme as:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

And adding falgs as follows before super.onCreate() in my invisible activity

```
        getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Now i can interact with the previous activity but the keyboard does not appear when needed (eg. login forms). Is there any possible solution to activate the keyboard while keeping the invisible activity running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to show the keyboard

```
final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(field, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

And this to hide

```
final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

You can perform it onResume() of your Activity.

Comment: Will try on monday, then will provide feedback thanks :)

Comment: Hey, we ended up implementing the interfaces we needed on the invisible activity on our main activity instead.